# ASP.NET-MVC . How to get the controller name from an url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I get the controller name of a relative Url, using the routes I have defined in Global.asax?

Example:

if I have a route defiend like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",                 // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", language = "en" }
```

from the string "~/en/products/list" I want to have products (the controller name). Is there any existing method that already does this?

Comment: Where is that going to be located at?

Comment: In an helper class that will extends UrlHelper

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830052/how-do-i-get-the-controller-and-action-names-from-the-referrer-uri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Stephen Walther's blog post [ASP.NET MVC Tip #13 – Unit Test Your Custom Routes](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/07/02/asp-net-mvc-tip-13-unit-test-your-custom-routes.aspx)

The project MvcFakes has an old System.Web.Abstractions reference. So you must replace it 
with the new one and recomply the project to get MvcFakes.dll.

This is my code:

```
public string getControllerNameFromUrl()
{
    RouteCollection rc = new RouteCollection();
    MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(rc);
    System.Web.Routing.RouteData rd = new RouteData();
    var context = new FakeHttpContext("\\" + HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
    rd = rc.GetRouteData(context);
    return rd.Values["action"].ToString();
}
```

In my code above "MvcApplication" is the class name in the Global.asax.

Good luck !

Comment: Stephen Walther's blog link above, still works.  However, once on his site, the download link fails and the link to Tip #12 also fails - so I cannot get a listing of the `FakeHttpContext` class.  Do you know of other places to get similar functionality?

Comment: Tip #12 is here: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/07/01/asp-net-mvc-tip-12-faking-the-controller-context

Answer (score 8):

You should probably add another route like George suggests but if you really just need the controller value derived from the route you can do this in your controller action methods:

```
var controller = (string)RouteData.Values["controller"];
```

Comment: How could I get the contrller name from an arbitrary url, not from RouteData?

Comment: @Gregoire? Do you mean an arbitrary URL on your site or someone else's? If on your site, then he told you how.

Comment: No because it will work only for the current URL, if I don't do a mistake (it works with Http current context)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking, so if my answer's wrong, it's because I'm guessing at what you want.

You can always add another route to your `Global.asax`. That's often the easiest way to deal with cases 'outside of the norm'.

If you want to return a list of products, you'll use this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ProductList",         
            "{language}/{products}/{action}/",
            new { controller = "Products", action = "List", language = "en" });
```

You can also replace products with the more generic `{controller}` if more than one type of entity is going to use this route. You should modify it for your needs.

For example, to make this a generic route that you can use to get a list of any product:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ProductList",         
            "{language}/{controller}/{action}/",
            new { controller = "Products", action = "List", language = "en" });
```

What this does is that it creates a route (that you should always place before your `Default` route) that says, "For whatever the user enters, give me the controller and action they ask for". (Such as `/en/Products/List`, or `/en/Users/List`).

To visit that controller, you simply need to navigate to the following: `yoursite.com/en/products/list`. You can also use the [`HTMLActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx) to visit the controller.

> `<%=Html.ActionLink("Product", "List", new { controller = Products }, null ) %>`

I'm writing this without my IDE open, so the `ActionLink` may have an error in it.

Comment: Thanks for having taking the time to answer me, but what I am looking for is a "reverse" GetRoute function, ie from an url (not the current one), I want to be able to extract the controller name

Comment: @Gregoire Great, uh, why didn't you say that in the first place?

Comment: Sorry but I have done a mistake because I believed it was clear enough