# Get file inside views folder in ASP.Net MVC 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory, mappath

I need to retrieve the name of a single view inside a `views\something` folder (comes from request) within MVC 4.0 and I'm not sure of how best to do it.

My code works but it has a 'hacky' feel to it and I was hoping someone could be simplified.

My code looks like:

```
    private FileInfo GetNameOfViewToServe()
    {
        var LeftPartOfUri = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
        var folder = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(LeftPartOfFolderUri,string.Empty);
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(@"~\Views\" + folder));
        return directory.GetFiles().First();
    }
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Any reason you don't store it in a database and have a Name to indentify it?  EG: http:\\mysite.com\submitreview -> db lookup for submitreview = ~\Views\submitreview.aspx

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's a brown field project and I have to work with what's there.  I just need a more elegant way of retrieving a list of files (usually only one from the relative request path.

Comment: can you show the controller action you are invoking?  Since it is MVC, can't your controller have a generic action that takes a string parameter and you can use reflection to create the view or a factory-like pattern that would return the view based off the string key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this solutions from question [ASP.NET-MVC . How to get the controller name from an url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592278/asp-net-mvc-how-to-get-the-controller-name-from-an-url) OR [Get ControllerName and ActionName and populate the ViewData in Master Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212429/get-controllername-and-actionname-and-populate-the-viewdata-in-master-page)

```
var controller = (string)RouteData.Values["controller"];
```

Comment: thanks, please see the comment above.  The controller used is generic and always returns 'PageController', which is not too helpful.

Comment: @davy I agree with Justin, you should look at reflection.