# MVC - Inverse of UrlHelper.RouteUrl / UrlHelper.Action methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Instead of looking for a way to provide a route to an action method, I'm looking for the inverse:

**how to derive the action method with route params from a URL in MVC?**

My usage of this is with Request.UrlReferrer where I'd like to parse that URL into a route so that I can have some 'back to' functionality.

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `Redirect(string url);`? In your case `Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer);`

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481565/string-url-to-routevaluedictionary

Comment: @AshleyMedway The trouble is I need to generate some text for the link based on where that link goes. e.g. 'Back to video games' or 'Back to apples'

Comment: Try this answer, you will need to modify it a little but should do what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/1632616/1398425